# Problems with mutable sets in Kotlin

Tags: for-loop, kotlin, input, set, ascii

I've recently started learning to program in Kotlin. As I tried to add a sequence of numbers to a mutable set using the for loop, the corresponding ASCII value was being added instead.

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  var userInput = readLine() //The input was 12345
  var set = mutableSetOf<Int>()
  for(n in userInput.orEmpty()){
    var numN = n.toInt()
    set.add(numN)
  }
  println(set)
}
// The output is [49, 50, 51, 52, 53], whereas I expected [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

At first I speculated the problem to be with the `.toInt()` function, so I tried this:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  var x = "2"
  println(x.toInt())
}
//The output is 2
```

But the output came as expected, the number itself, not the corresponding ASCII version.

Now how am I supposed to fix this, so that I get my expected result in the first code?

I'm yet a novice in this programming language, so there could be any hilarious mistakes in my code as well.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because `n` is a `Char` and the method `Char.toInt()` returns its ASCII value.

To avoid that, you should convert the `Char` into a `String` and then use `String.toInt()` (like you have done in the sample with the value `"2"`).

```kotlin
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var userInput = readLine() //The input was 12345
    var set = mutableSetOf<Int>()
    for(n in userInput.orEmpty()){
        var numN = n.toString().toInt()
        set.add(numN)
    }
    println(set)
}
```

By the way, you obtain the same result with way less code:

```kotlin
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var userInput = readLine() //The input was 12345
    // 1. Converts the string to an array of char
    // 2. Transforms each char into its number value
    // 3. Converts the result list in a set
    val set = userInput.orEmpty().toCharArray().map(Character::getNumericValue).toSet()
    println(set)
}
```